# Download attachments using Microsoft Graph v5 in C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to download attachments with a specific name from my shared mailbox using Microsoft Graph API. I can see that there are content bytes inside the object. I am not able to convert it to file and save it to the destination path.

[image: Here you can see the content bytes inside the file object.]

Using this code to download the file in C#:

```
if (attachmentId != null)
            {
                var file = await graphServiceClient.Users[email].Messages[messageId].Attachments[attachmentId.Id].GetAsync();
                //File.WriteAllBytes("D:\\", file);
            }
```

What can I do here to download the attachments using Microsoft Graph?

Answer (score 0):

SDK doesn't support to get directly the content stream but as a workaround you can create a request to read the content as a stream

```
var rawAttachmentInfo = graphServiceClient.Users[email].Messages[messageId].Attachments[attachmentId.Id].ToGetRequestInformation();
rawAttachmentInfo.URI = new Uri(rawAttachmentInfo.URI.OriginalString + "/$value");

using var attachmentStream = await graphServiceClient.RequestAdapter.SendPrimitiveAsync<Stream>(rawAttachmentInfo);
using var fs = File.OpenWrite("Path");
await attachmentStream.CopyToAsync(fs);
```